GoogleJib is stuck at 80 percent while creating docker image
While trying to create a docker image for spring boot app using the
mvn compile jib:dockerBuild getting below error
enter image description here
I am using GoogleJib to create a docker image for my springboot application. but It is getting stuck at 80 percent. Since I do not see any logs except the below Screenshot. Options  I have tried

Restart system
Sign in /Sign out from docker
Restart docker
Uninstall-Install Docker

PS: The image is attached but need to click on link

Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.  As you've written it, the question is pretty much only a link to an image and nothing else.  Can you [edit] the question to include a [mcve], making sure to include the logs and source code in plain text?

I was also facing the same but it was resolved to me by following the below steps

changed the jib-maven-plugin to an older version in pom.xml. e.g 3.3.2

Now This gave me the correct error telling my java version in pom is 21 but the base docker image it is trying to create is using 17
I) Try changing the version of Java to 17 in Pom (or)
ii) Try adding the below in the configuration of plugin (I followed this)
         <from>
             <image>eclipse-temurin:21-jre</image> 
         </from>



FYI my issue was with java version so it got resolved for by following above steps.

Try to change jib-maven-plugin to older version in pom.xml. e.g 3.3.2

yes it worked after changing the version

I also fought with the same problem:
Building Image not proceeding further 80%
This is happening due to using unstabilized jib versions in our project, those may take some more time to work as of now use jib version 3.3.2 which is the latest stabilized version of jib.
Change jib version to 3.3.2
after changing the version, it generated an image for me.
Image build successfully
